# Group By on a DataSheetView

Tags: sharepoint-designer, datasheet, grouping

I have a DataSheet view on my library of infopath forms. the forms are basically weekly status reports and what i want to do is total the hours from each report for the month and show a totals row. I assume this could be done with a group by field, but there is no option to group by with a datasheet view. Does anyone have a way around this?

Comment: Is this 2007 or 2010? Is there any particular reason why it needs to be a datasheet view? Do you have the columns set up to allow for writing back to the form so that they can be modified in the datasheet view? Or are you just trying to get a better presentation from the view and the standard view totals do not quite pull it off. I personally think a XSLT view web part/data view web part would be the best way to go from a presentation side of things.

Comment: Yea I am trying to mimick the look of an excel spreadsheet we currently use. the data in the view will be read only since it is pulling the info from the infopath form i have developed. I am somewhat new to this do you have an example or tutorial that shows how to use xslt with a data view web part i may be able to use as a reference?

Comment: also I forgot to mention I am in 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to have the "spreadsheet" quality of a DataSheet View and use Group By, even using SharePoint Designer or jQuery. The closest functionality would be to use a regular view with grouping and allow inline editing (which is an option in the View Setting page). This will allow someone to edit one line at a time, but not perform group edits.

If group editing and Group By is needed (such as to allow copy / paste from a spreadsheet) then I use this 2007 Excel add-in that allows syncing between an Excel Sheet and a SharePoint list and perform the edits in Excel. The add-in works with 2010 also.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9345